# iOS app gets stuck after opening it from background state

Tags: ios, objective-c, background-process

My iOS app is getting stuck when I open that from background state(when app is running in the background). I have to wait for at least 5-6 seconds for my app to respond.
This also happens when my app is open and I lock the device and when I unlock the device, the device also gets stuck for 5-6 seconds and same thing happens as above.
I am not able to find any cause for this problem and had searched about it lot but couldn't find any solution.

Any help would be much appreciated.

P.S. My app doesn't execute any background operation and it also not registered for background operations.

Comment: Put some breakpoints in `AppDelegate`?

Comment: post your code in `applicationDidLaunchWithOptions`

Comment: Is there anything in applicationWillEnterForeground or applicationDidBecomeActive?

Comment: resolved the issue, the main cause was connection establishment of UDP socket in applicationWillEnterForeground, so fixed that issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the issue, the main cause was connection establishment of UDP socket in applicationWillEnterForeground.
So, modified the code where UDP socket tries to establish network connection.
Thanks